# How to fetch live stream video details from webcam via browser to python?

Tags: python, opencv, webrtc

I am working to detect faces and emotions from live stream video using python,tensorflow,opencv and usbcamera.
Its working fine via terminal in local. I try to run webcam through browser.
How to send video stream via webrtc to python.
Is it possible to fetch webrtc result frame by frame using python because i want to do some process in here.

Comment: If you are focusing  on browser implementation of ML I suggest you use their javascript implementation. Tensorflow.js and Keras.js are available and you can even use your python trained models in tf.js. In this approach all the processing takes place on client machine. Check this implementation out: https://github.com/ModelDepot/tfjs-yolo-tiny

Comment: Thank you for your comment!. How can i import python train model in tensorflow.js

Comment: [https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-keras-model-tensorflowjs-tutorial/?completed=/pong-ai-tensorflowjs-tutorial/]
Use this. It has a video tutorial accompanying the text explanation.

Comment: These files i want to convert kerasmodel to tfjs Face_model_architecture.json,Face_model_weights.h5.
 I posted my code below is it correct?

Comment: Finally i found the solution for detect face and emotions in stream video via browser like a webapplication.   I reffer this links : brendansudol.com/writing/tfjs-emotions, github.com/tupleblog/face-classification-js

Answer (score 0):

I converted my keras trained model to tfjs i had model.json file.
How to load the converted model into js file
I need model.predict_class() for detect face emotions.
How to import webcam.js for live stream in js for access web cam

```
convert_model_krs_tfjs.py
-------------------------
import keras
from keras.models import model_from_json 
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

model = model_from_json(open('Face_model_architecture.json').read())
model.load_weights('Face_model_weights.h5')
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
model.save("Keras-64x2-10epoch")
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "face")

My python worked code:
----------------------
detectemotion.py
----------------
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
model = model_from_json(open('./models/Face_model_architecture.json').read())
#model.load_weights('_model_weights.h5')
model.load_weights('./models/Face_model_weights.h5')
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
print(model)
def extract_face_features(gray, detected_face, offset_coefficients):
        (x, y, w, h) = detected_face
        #print x , y, w ,h
        horizontal_offset = np.int(np.floor(offset_coefficients[0] * w))
        vertical_offset = np.int(np.floor(offset_coefficients[1] * h))


        extracted_face = gray[y+vertical_offset:y+h, 
                          x+horizontal_offset:x-horizontal_offset+w]
        #print extracted_face.shape
        new_extracted_face = zoom(extracted_face, (48. / extracted_face.shape[0], 
                                               48. / extracted_face.shape[1]))
        new_extracted_face = new_extracted_face.astype(np.float32)
        new_extracted_face /= float(new_extracted_face.max())
        return new_extracted_face
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
def detect_face(frame):
        cascPath = "./models/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        detected_faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray,
                scaleFactor=1.1,
                minNeighbors=6,
                minSize=(48, 48),
                flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
            )
        return gray, detected_faces

import cv2
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
#    sleep(0.8)
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # detect faces
    gray, detected_faces = detect_face(frame)

    face_index = 0

    # predict output
    for face in detected_faces:
        (x, y, w, h) = face
        if w > 100:
            # draw rectangle around face 
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

            # extract features
            extracted_face = extract_face_features(gray, face, (0.075, 0.05)) #(0.075, 0.05)

            # predict smile
            prediction_result = model.predict_classes(extracted_face.reshape(1,48,48,1))

            # draw extracted face in the top right corner
            frame[face_index * 48: (face_index + 1) * 48, -49:-1, :] = cv2.cvtColor(extracted_face * 255, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

            # annotate main image with a label
            if prediction_result == 3:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Happy!!",(x,y), cv2.FONT_ITALIC, 2, (255,255,255), 2)
            elif prediction_result == 0:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Angry",(x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255,255,255), 2)
        elif prediction_result == 1:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Disgust",(x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255,255,255), 2)
        elif prediction_result == 2:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Fear",(x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255,255,255), 2)
        elif prediction_result == 4:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Sad",(x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255,255,255), 2)
        elif prediction_result == 5:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Surprise",(x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,(255,255,255), 2)
        else :
                cv2.putText(frame, "Neutral",(x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,(255,255,255), 2)


            # increment counter
            face_index += 1


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```